# How sould persistance unit for EJB app using in memory database look like?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, derby, jta

I have an Java app, which i used to test with this persistence unit with in memory Derby driver:

```
<persistence-unit name="TestPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:ProjectDB"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
</properties>
```

Now i added an EJB service layer and i have been unable to write a working persistence unit using the same in memory db since. The following works fine, but i'd like to have it in memory

```
<persistence-unit name="moduleNamePU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
</properties>
```

How can i alter the second persistence unit in order to work with in memory db?

EDIT: As an EJB container i use Glassfish 3.1

Entity Service:

```
@Stateless
@Local(value=EntityServiceLocal.class)
public class EntityService implements EntityServiceLocal {

    @EJB
    private EntityDaoLocal entityDao;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    public void setEntityDao(EntityDaoLocal entityDao) {
        this.entityDao = entityDao;
    }
}
```

Dao Layer service:

```
@Stateless
public class EntityDao implements EntityDaoLocal {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details as to - what's your EJB container (jboss, weblogic, OpenEJB )? How is your datasource created? Please post your datasource configuration code.

Comment: I edited my post so as to provide the answers. If you need any more, please tell me.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. Have you created a datasource in Glassfish with jndi name set to 'jdbc/sample' ?

Comment: You mean via web.xml and glassfish-web.xml? No, not yet.

Comment: Looks like that's what you are missing. Please follow this tutorial to create a datasource using glassfish admin console. Make sure your jndi datasource name is 'jdbc/sample'. http://musabalrawi.com/2011/06/configure-datasource-on-glassfish/